# Virtual Memory and pages in RAM

Tags: unix, memory, ram, virtual-memory

In a system with virtual memory, when the pages of a process are swapped from HD to RAM is it true that all the pages are always put in Swap Area? Or only the pages that not fit in RAM are put in Swap Area?

Which one of these two situations happens?

Comment: A page refers to an entire mapping of all addresses. Therefore you can only have one active page at any point in time. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_(computer_memory)

Answer (score 0):

Swapping is the memory management technique where the entire process is stored on disk. Swapping was common in the days of 64kb address spaces where it did not take many disk I/O operations to store an entire process. Processes are stored in a swap file.

Pages is the memory management technique where individual pages are stored on disk. Pages are stored in a page file.

Some systems use both swapping and paging. For example, Windoze has recently reintroduced swapping.